# Where can I find checkstyle config for Android Coding Style?

Tags: android, coding-style, checkstyle

There are [Coding Conventions](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) for Android.
They include some stuff like naming conventions that can be checked using checkstyle.

I've found some config for checkstyle: http://ksoichiro.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-checkstyle.html

But I want to ask if there is some more complete config for checkstyle. Maybe Google provide some official checkstyle config?

Comment: I don't think Google provides any official one..

Comment: Rules for formatting in Eclipse are available: https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/master/ide/eclipse/android-formatting.xml I know this doesn't answer the exact question (Checkstyle) but it is from the Android people.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here you can find some that implement http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html
although none of them is official.

- [Eclipse checkstyle checks for Android](https://gist.github.com/948425)
- [Checkstyles in the swp-dv-ws2010-osm-1 project](https://code.google.com/p/swp-dv-ws2010-osm-1/source/browse/trunk/TraceBook/checks.xml)
- [Android CheckStyle (Japanese website)](http://ksoichiro.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-checkstyle.html)
- [Android-getting started guide](https://sites.google.com/site/lapndaandroid/android-getting-started)

Comment: A version for the current Checkstyle version 5.6 can be found at:
https://gist.github.com/shareme/4197561

Comment: Do these work for Android studio. If so till what version?

Comment: @VishnooRath you must add apropriate gradle task to ruch checkstyle

Answer (score 8):

There is Android Check plugin (https://github.com/noveogroup/android-check).

It has two predefined Checkstyle configurations you can use:

- [checkstyle-easy.xml](https://github.com/noveogroup/android-check/blob/master/android-check-plugin/src/main/resources/checkstyle/checkstyle-easy.xml)
- [checkstyle-hard.xml](https://github.com/noveogroup/android-check/blob/master/android-check-plugin/src/main/resources/checkstyle/checkstyle-hard.xml)

Comment: I am pretty new to this. Could you please explain how can i import these settings to my Android studio? I have tried importing to the Inspections section in Android studio common settings. I have QA plug - PMD, Checkstyle and Findbugs installed.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the checkstyle configuration used for Picasso by Square folks:
   https://github.com/square/picasso/blob/master/checkstyle.xml

Here is Google's Java Style Checkstyle Coverage:
  http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/google_style.html

Answer (score 4):

CheckStyle for Android:

- CheckStyle.
- PMD.
- Findbugs.

To add a dependency to gradle: [Gradle Plugin for Android](https://github.com/nrudenko/gradle-android-cq-plugin)

[More info on the Blog](http://sethrylan.org/2013/07/14/gradle-android-findbugs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html

I have also gone through their source (GrepCode is good) to look at their styling.  You could create a custom Eclipse formatter based on these rules.

**EDIT**

Very sorry did not see your link above.  I am unaware of anything like this.  Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: I provided this link in question text, so I know about this coding style description. I am interested in Checkstyle tool config.